# Correctly publish a Flux to multiple streams being merged later on

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am developing on a project utilizing Project Reactor, and due to requirements of the
project, I often have to retrieve values from an API, and then both store the result and return it.
What is the best way to do this?
Currently, I implemented it in the following way:

```
void main() {
    getAndSaveBirds()
      .subscribe(bird -> System.out.println(bird));
}

Flux<Bird> getAndSaveBirds() {
    Flux<Bird> birds = api.getBirds().cache();
    return birds.collectList()
            .doOnSuccess(birdList -> performSideEffect(birdList))
            .thenMany(birds);
}
```

But I am thinking that this might be a wasteful approach, as I now would save each `Bird`
unnecessarily.
I was considering the `.share()` operator, but the documentation regarding it is very sparse.

Which operator/program flow would be the correct here?

Comment: Is db.persistBirds(List<>) blocking? Is it a database call? What db are you using? And why do you perform this operation in .doOnSuccess()? It is not correct.

Comment: Yes, it is a blocking call, the db should not be relevant, as I put it only as an example
Why is `.doOnSuccess()` not correct?

Comment: doOnSuccess() as described in reactor documentation is meant to add some side effect without affecting the original sequence. Here you put there a blocking operation directly which blocks the executing thread, therefore, you "break" reactive chain as it is supposed to be non-blocking, otherwise you'll lose the benefits of reactive way. Take a look here to find out how to wrap a blocking call https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: Also, why I'm asking about the database, because it could be related to answer to your question. For example, if you use mongodb, which has the reactive driver and reactive spring data support, then you could use .flatMap(birdList -> repo.saveAll(birdList)) which would return Flux<Bird> (flux of saved birds), so you could return it directly from your method, without any extra needs.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!
To keep the purpose of the question, I reworked the example